# How can I find parent object of a child and enabled true the child?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top of the script :

```
public GameObject naviParent;
```

The parent is just empty GameObject

Then I want to find the child of this parent the child is enabled false when the game start !

I did later in the script :

```
GameObject navi = naviParent.Find("NAVI Destination");
```

But getting error on naviParent.Find

Member 'GameObject.Find(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

I want to enable true the child of the parent the child.

Comment: `naviParent.transform` exposes an enumerator. So you can `foreach` over it and find your child. Unity Docs example: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there is both [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) which is `static` and there is [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) which is not.

They do different things:

- [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) searches in the entire Scene Hierarchy and returns the first encountered **active** object with given name.

  If this is what you intend then you would use it without an instance since as said it is static:

  ```
  GameObject navi = GameObject.Find("NAVI Destination");
  ```
- [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) searches a first level child only on the given `Transform` reference. If the object is further nested it will not be found unless you provide a full relative path like

  ```
  someTransform.Find("SomeFirstLevelChild/SomeSecondLevelChild/SearchedObjectName");
  ```

  So you probably wanted to use

  ```
  GameObject navi = naviParent.transform.Find("NAVI Destination").gameObject;
  ```

  which as said will only work if `NAVI Destination` is a direct child of the `naviParent` object.

---

If you want to be able to also find nested inactive children as well you could do something like

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public Transform FindRecursive(this Transform transform, string name)
    {
        var children = transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);

        foreach(var child in children)
        {
            if(child == transform) continue;
       
            if(child.name.Equals(name))
            {
                return child;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
GameObject navi = naviParent.transform.FindRecursive("NAVI Destination").gameObject;
```